# change color in liquid slider

Tags: jquery, html, css

I implemented [LiquidSlider](http://liquidslider.com/) into a website that I'm developing. It works flawlessly, however I do have one question that I cant seem to find an answer to.

Can I change the background color? The div that I have it in is grey and I want to either change the background color to the same color or just make it transparent. How do I do this?

This is what Ive tried so far

```
 .ls-wrapper {
    background-color:transparent;
  margin:0 auto;
  /* Do not edit below this line */
  clear: both;
  overflow: auto;
  position: relative;
}

/******************************************************
* Main Container
* This is the main container (minus the navigation).
* Be sure to match the width with the .panel class, 
* or it won't work properly. Also, width only applies
* if you are not using the responsive setting.
*
* The responsive slider will interpret the width as the
* max width instead
*******************************************************/
.ls-wrapper .liquid-slider {
  background-color:transparent;
  width: 1030px;
  /* Do not edit below this line */
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
```

Comment: Can you post a sample on jsfiddle.net?

Comment: http://www.voipstreet.com/testSite/index.html

Comment: So basically you want the top part (Titanium, origination...) to be gray?

Comment: No i want the actual slider to be grey like the area behind it.

Comment: Oh my bad. Didn't notice actual slider at first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set both these to transparent it works.

```
.panel
{
    background: transparent;
}

.liquid-slider
{
    background: transparent;
}
```

`.panel` is the background to each slide.

`.liquid-slider` is the background to the whole slider.

Their is also a `border-color` set to each panel you can add `border-color: transparent` to `.panel` to clear this.

Comment: This works great. Any chance you can inform me as to how to remove the white line around the slider?. Edit - Perfect. THANKS!

Comment: @onTheInternet Sure i updated my answer to show you how to fix it.